# error trying to implement 32-bit adder

Tags: verilog

I am trying to add two 32 bits numbers using verilog.But I am getting many dont-care in the resut.
The 32 bit adder uses 4 8-bit adders.One 8 -bit adder uses one bit Full-Adder.FAdder makes use of 3 to 8 decoder.
Here is my code-

```
module Decoder(D,x,y,z);
    input x,y,z;
    output [0:7] D;
    wire xn,yn,zn;

    not n1(xn,x);
    not n2(yn,y);
    not n3(zn,z);

    and a1(D[0],xn,yn,zn);
    and a2(D[1],xn,yn,z);
    and a3(D[2],xn,y,zn);
    and a4(D[3],xn,y,z);
    and a5(D[4],x,yn,zn);
    and a6(D[5],x,yn,z);
    and a7(D[6],x,y,zn);
    and a8(D[7],x,y,z);
endmodule

module FAdder(S,C,x,y,z);
    input x,y,z;
    output S,C;
    wire [0:7] D;

    Decoder dec(D,x,y,z);

    assign S= D[1] | D[2] | D[4] | D[7];
    assign C= D[3] | D[5] | D[6] | D[7];

endmodule


module eightbitAdder(S,Carry,in1,in2,z);
    input [7:0] in1;
    input [7:0] in2;
    input z;
    output [7:0] S;
    output Carry;
    wire  C[7:0]; 
    assign z=0;
    FAdder F1(S[0],C[0],in1[0],in2[0],z);
    FAdder F2(S[1],C[1],in1[1],in2[1],C[0]);
    FAdder F3(S[2],C[2],in1[2],in2[2],C[1]);
    FAdder F4(S[3],C[3],in1[3],in2[3],C[2]);
    FAdder F5(S[4],C[4],in1[4],in2[4],C[3]);
    FAdder F6(S[5],C[5],in1[5],in2[5],C[4]);
    FAdder F7(S[6],C[6],in1[6],in2[6],C[5]);
    FAdder F8(S[7],C[7],in1[7],in2[7],C[6]);
    assign Carry=C[7];
endmodule

module t32bitadder(S,Carry1,in1,in2);
    input [31:0] in1,in2;
    output [31:0] S;
    output Carry1;
    wire [3:0] C1;
    wire initCarry;
    assign initCarry=0;
    eightbitAdder e1(S[7:0],C1[0],in1[7:0],in2[7:0],initCarry);
    eightbitAdder e2(S[15:8],C1[1],in1[15:8],in2[15:8],C1[0]);
    eightbitAdder e3(S[23:16],C1[2],in1[23:16],in2[23:16],C1[1]);
    eightbitAdder e4(S[31:24],C1[3],in1[31:24],in2[31:24],C1[2]);
    assign Carry1=C1[3];
endmodule

module testbench32bitAdder;
   reg [31:0] in1,in2;
   reg z;
   wire [31:0] S;
   wire C;
   t32bitadder Al(S,C,in1,in2);

   initial
      $monitor(,$time,"in1=%b,in2=%b,S=%b,C=%b",in1,in2,S,C);

   initial
      begin
         #0 in1=32'b00000001000000010000000110000001;in2=32'b00000001000000010000000110000001;
         #4 in1=32'b11000001100000011000000100000001;in2=32'b11000001100000010000000100000001;
         #4 in1=32'b00000001000000010000000100000001;in2=32'b10000001000000010000000100000001;


      end
```

This is the result I am getting-

```
#                     0in1=00000001000000010000000110000001,in2=00000001000000010000000110000001,S=0000001000000010000000xx00000010,C=0
#                     4in1=11000001100000011000000100000001,in2=11000001100000010000000100000001,S=100000xx000000101000001000000010,C=1
#                     8in1=00000001000000010000000100000001,in2=10000001000000010000000100000001,S=10000010000000100000001000000010,C=0
```

Notice the dont-care in the second output. This is because of the C1[2] which becomes `X` . Can anyone  point out my mistake?

Comment: In the eightbitAdder module, you seem to do this, 
    assign z=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vipin is correct, the `assign z=0;` line in the `eightbitAdder` module is leading to the dont cares. In your test, the carry out of the first 8-bit adder is 1, it attempts to set the `z` input to the next 8-bit adder to 1, but this conflicts with the continuous assignment of `z` to 0, thus resulting in `z = 1'bx`. This dont care is propagated through the first FA and impacts the second as well, which results in the 2 dont cares in the 8th and 9th places of the result (where the first bit is the 0th place). The same thing is happening between your third and your final 8-bit adders in the second test. Your third test doesnt propagate a carry between 8-bit adders so no dont cares are generated.